# Find the radius of the sector adjoining a triangle

Tags: circles, triangles, plane-geometry

[image: [img]https://i.imgsafe.org/5172eee94d.jpg [/img]]

We know that the area of the sector should be $\frac{40}{360}\cdot\frac{22}{7}\cdot r^2$

Any ideas on how to begin?

Many Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius, then the area of the triangle is 
$$ A = \frac{1}{2}2 \pi r $$ 
and the area of the sector is 
$$
A = \frac{40}{360} \pi r^2
$$
Setting these equal gives you one equation with one unknown
$$
\frac{1}{2}2 \pi r = \frac{40}{360} \pi r^2
$$
which you can solve for $r$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}2 \pi r = \frac{40}{360} \pi r^2$;
$\pi r                       =\frac{1}{9} \pi r^2$;
$9\pi r                       =\pi r^2$; From there?

Comment: @user360471 right, and you can also cancel a factor of $\pi r$ from both sides.

Comment: $9(\pi r)                       =(\pi r$)$r$;
$9 cm=r$. Correct?

Comment: @user360471 Looks good.  You can check it by plugging in $9$ for $r$ in both equations and making sure both give you the same area.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}×2 ×\frac{22}{7}× 9 = \frac{22}{7} ×\frac{40}{360}× 9^2$;
$\frac{22}{7}× 9 = \frac{22}{7} ×\frac{40}{360}× 81$ ,Looks like cannot be simplified.

Comment: @user360471 Lol just use a calculator ;p  You pointed out earlier that 40/360 = 1/9, so your last two factors of $\frac{40}{360} \times 81$ gives you 9.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}×2 ×\frac{22}{7}× 9 = \frac{22}{7} ×\frac{40}{360}× 9^2$;
$\frac{22}{7}× 9 = \frac{22}{7} ×\frac{1}{9}× 81$;
$\frac{22}{7}× 9 = \frac{22}{7} × 9$; Correct I Guess?

Comment: Correct!  The left side equals the right.  The radius is 9.